# How to make Facebook Open Graph change image and title on every share

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to do a marketing campaign where every time a user shares a specific page, it shows up a different title, image and description. The problem is that Facebook caches this data for 24h.

I've tried to used Facebook API to send a Curl to Facebook Debugger to force it to refresh before the HTML is loaded, but with no success. https://gist.github.com/FrostyX/81d58222d1e835e24013

```
<?php
  require_once('FacebookDebugger.php');
  $fb = new FacebookDebugger();
  $fb->reload('http://example.com/'); // this page
?>
<html>
<head>
<?php
  $var = array( 
  "first" => array(
              "title" => "First test",
              "image" => "https://example.com/1.jpg"
              ), 
  "second" => array(
              "title" => "Second test",
              "image" => "https://example.com/2.jpg"
              ), 
  "third" => array(
              "title" => "Third test",
              "image" => "https://example.com/3.jpg"
              ), 
  );

  $section = array_rand($var); // choose a random item on the array above
?>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<meta name="twitter:card" value="summary"> 
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $var[$section]['title']; ?>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $var[$section]['image']; ?>"  />
```

I already seen a couple web pages doing it. How can I achieve this?

Examples:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=marvelfly.com
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=f-u-t-b-o-l.com

Comment: Would you care to specify why the vote down?

Comment: This is a question that is asked often, likely why you got downvoted. Search and youll find quite a few answers. Heres one though, FB caches based on unique url, to force a refresh, you can just add a randomized query string to the url. You could write some javascript that appends a random string to the url whenever the share button is clicked on your site. There is no way to do this (that im aware of) if your user is copy pasting your url themselves. Cheers!

Comment: @JonChurch, debug this website, for example: f-u-t-b-o-l.com

Comment: Or this one: marvelfly.com - How do they do that?

Comment: Share a unique URL every time

Comment: @WizKid debug marvelfly.com, for example

Comment: Don't share marvelfly.com. Share marvelfly.com?ref=asdjaskjd where ref is different every time

Comment: @WizKid https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=marvelfly.com

Comment: You said that. I said don't share that URL. Share a unique URL.

Comment: @WizKid but did you see that debugging that specific URL gives a different title, image and description every time?

Comment: We already told you several times how to solve it. If you don't want to do that then that is up to you. But there is no reason to continue discussing

Comment: @WizKid no problem buddy, but I'm just saying that if you debug marvelfly.com, you will get a different image and title every time without having to change the URL, that's different than what you are saying.

Comment: You said that Facebook caches the result for 24 hours.

Comment: @WizKid yes it does, thus this question

Comment: And that is the question we answered. Use a unique URL.

Comment: @WizKid holly crap man, but how do marvefly.com and f-u-t-b-o-l.com refreshes theirs without changing their URL?

Comment: @WizKid I finally understood you were meaning og:url >.>

Answer (score 0):

I did it with cron.

HTML:

```
<?php
  $var = array( 
  "um" => array(
              "titulo" => "Produto 1",
              "image" => "http://tudosobrecachorros.com.br/wp-content/uploads/cachorros-pequenos.jpg"
              ), 
  "dois" => array(
              "titulo" => "Produto 2",
              "image" => "http://tudosobrecachorros.com.br/wp-content/uploads/precos-de-cachorro.png"
              ), 
  "tres" => array(
              "titulo" => "Produto 3",
              "image" => "http://tudosobrecachorros.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/nomes-para-cachorros.jpeg"
              ), 
  );

  $section = array_rand($var); //here yoy get random first of array(green or red or yellow)
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<meta name="twitter:card" value="summary">
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $var[$section]['titulo']; ?>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://YOUR-URL-HERE.COM/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $var[$section]['image']; ?>"  />
<meta property="og:description" content="Somente um teste"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-iBcUE/x23aI6syuqF7EeT/+JFBxjPs5zeFJEXxumwb0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<title>Somente um teste</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Refresh.php (should fire on cron every few seconds)

```
<?php
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com';
    $fields = array(
                'id'=>urlencode('http://YOUR-URL-HERE.COM'),
                'scrape'=>urlencode(true)
            );

    //url-ify the data for the POST
    $fields_string = '';
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string,'&');

    //echo $fields_string;exit;

    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    print $result;
?>
```

crontab -e

```
* * * * * for i in {0..59}; do curl http://YOUR-URL-HERE.com/refresh.php && sleep 10; done;
```

Comment: Hi! Are you able to solve this? I believe cron's minimum time is 1 minute right?